# Integral question: $\int \frac{x^{5}+x+3}{x{^3}-5x^{2}}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

i have integral $\int \frac{x^{5}+x+3}{x{^3}-5x^{2}}\mathrm  dx$,

so first step is to divide polynoms, and i get:

$\frac{x^{5}+x+3}{x{^3}-5x^{2}}$ = $x^{2} + 5x + 25$ with remainder $125x^2 + x + 3$

is it corrent to divide this polynomial division into two integrals:

**int 1:** $\int x^{2}+5x+25 \mathrm dx$

**int 2:** $\int \frac{125x^{2}+x+3}{x{^2}(x-5)}\mathrm dx$

first integral solve directly from tables, and make partial fractions from second integral, then just merge solutions into one expression.

Comment: Yes. It is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is all correct.

$$
   x^5 + x^2 + 3 = 125 x^2 + x + 3 + (x^3-5 x^2)(x^2 + 5 x + 25)
$$
Hence
$$
 \begin{eqnarray}
   \frac{x^5 + x + 3 }{x^3-5 x^2} &=& x^2 + 5 x + 25 + \frac{125 x^2 +x+ 3}{x^3-5 x} \\ &=& 
   x^2 + 5 x + 25 -\frac{3}{5 \, x^2} - \frac{8}{25 x} + \frac{3133}{25} \frac{x - 5}{x^2-5} \end{eqnarray}
$$

Therefore

$$
 \int \frac{x^5 + x + 3 }{x^3-5 x^2} \mathrm{d} x = 
   \left(\frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{5}{2} x^2 + 25 x\right) + \left( \frac{3}{5} \frac{1}{x} - \frac{8}{25} \log x + \frac{3133}{25} \log(x-5)  \right) + C
$$

Comment: @Thijs Yes, indeed, thank you. I will edit the post.

Answer (score 2):

**I liked the problem,so i decided to offer you a step by step solution.you may want to to go through this if you are after a step by step solution**

**As you can see the degree of the numerator is greater than the degree of the denominator you have divided using long division and have obtained an other expression which is**

**$$x^2 + 5x + 125 + \frac{125x^2 + x + 3}{x^2(x - 5)}$$**

You must observe that the denominator is a product of a quadratic and a linear factor of the form

**$$\frac{Ax + B}{ax^2 + bx +c} + \frac{C}{x + d}$$**

Now use the Partial Fraction decomposition method to decompose the fraction into

**$$\frac{-3}{5x^2} - \frac{8}{25x} + \frac{3133}{25(x-5)}$$**

Now you can use the appropriate integral tricks to evaluate it.

Ok:I'am giving you the hint as per request.

**$$\frac{Ax + B}{x^2} + \frac{C}{x-5}$$**

Next step is to add the fraction after finding the common denominator.I think this should suffice!

Comment: +1 But can you also give a hint about how you did this partial fraction decomposition? Thanks...(I noticed that your $\TeX$ing is better already, keep it up! :))

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct. Decompose integral 2 as partial fraction:
$$\frac{125x^{2}+x+3}{x{^2}(x-5)} = -\frac{3}{5 x^2}-\frac{8}{25 x}+\frac{3133}{25 (x-5)}
$$